# Add small element inside H1 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

I am trying to change the content of a h1 which has a  element inside it. However, when the button triggers the text change, the H1 is applied but the small styling is not applied.

```
Here's the html:
<h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title" id="singlePrice">$55
<small class="text-muted"> / month</small>
</h1>
```

This is my jQuery:

// Change price with click on annual button

```
   $('#annual').click(function(){
        $('#singlePrice').html('<h1 >$48 <small> / month </small> </h1>');
        console.log("I got clicked");
    })
```

Comment: You are setting an h1 inside of an h1.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an h1 inside of an h1. You just want to set the content that is inside of the h1.

```js
$('#annual').click(function() {
  $('#singlePrice').html('$48 <small class="text-muted"> / month </small>');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-GQGU0fMMi238uA+a/bdWJfpUGKUkBdgfFdgBm72SUQ6BeyWjoY/ton0tEjH+OSH9iP4Dfh+7HM0I9f5eR0L/4w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title" id="singlePrice">$55
      <small class="text-muted"> / month</small>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>


<button id='annual'>X</button>
```

Comment: thanks for answering but am still not seeing the small styling applied to the / month text when I run your code. i have tried appending the small tag but doesn't work either

Comment: You do not have the class "text-muted" on the small that you replace it with.